# Grails unit test of domain class (gorm)

Tags: hibernate, unit-testing, grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

Started playing with grails and I want to evaluate GORM, so I created a domain class using Spring Tool Suite: `Client` with `name`, `vatNumber`, and `regNumber` and the test class was created automatically.

The code for unit test I added is :

```
package pilot1

import grails.test.*

class ClientTests extends GrailsUnitTestCase {
    protected void setUp() {
        super.setUp()
    }

    protected void tearDown() {
        super.tearDown()
    }

    void testSomething() {
        def instances = []
        def myTestDomain = mockDomain(Client, instances)
        def client = new Client(name:"Test",vatNumber:"323",regNumber:"343")
        client.id =1;
        assertEquals client.name, "Test"
        client.save();
        def res = Client.findByName("Test")
        println instances
        println res
        //assertEquals 1, instances.size()
    }
}
```

The results are [] and null! What did I do wrong?

Also, I would like also to see the SQL generated by GORM (Hibernate) behind the scenes. Any idea how I might do that in Grails ?

Comment: If you are using this as a unit test, Hibernate isn't actually used, and there is no SQL usage. It's all mocked, and some of the more subtle queries (most of them, in my limited experience) tend not to find stuff. Integration tests do real Hibernate stuff.

Comment: i read something about this but i was not sure ! hmmmm that is strange coming from java...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-grails10148/index.html

"As I mentioned earlier, Grails supports two basic types of tests: unit and integration. There's no syntactical difference between the two — both are written as a GroovyTestCase using the same assertions. The difference is the semantics. A unit test is meant to test the class in isolation, whereas the integration test allows you to test the class in a full, running environment.
Quite frankly, if you want to write all of your Grails tests as integration tests, that's just fine with me. All of the Grails create-* commands generate corresponding integration tests, so most folks simply use what is already there. As you'll see in just a moment, most of the things you want to test require the full environment to be up and running anyway, so integration tests are a pretty good default."

Comment: Exactly. Just that "most of the things you want to test require the full environment to be up and running anyway" is a pretty bad advice.

Comment: mockDomain(Client, instances) allows for a lot of Gorm functionalities to be tested without having the full environment up and running. Search for the mockDomain section and examples in http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/9.%20Testing.html#9.1%20Unit%20Testing for detailed information.

Comment: Integration tests vs. unit tests does not matter that much when running them in batch, but when running a single test or test case, e.g. when developing it, a unit test is much faster than an integration test.

Comment: What do you mean when running them in batch ?

Answer (score 2):

don't do this: client.id =1;

save() will supply an id.

you may need to save(flush:true).

just do the save and use then use the id to do a get.

then do your testing.

this link may be useful: http://blog.springsource.com/2011/06/07/countdown-to-grails-1-4-unit-testing/

Answer (score 1):

First, you shouldn't be evaluating GORM itself.  Those who provide Grails take on the responsibility for testing GORM.  Granted, you probably didn't mean that anyway.

Second, testing findBy*() is not usually the concern for unit tests.  If you do need to test findBy*(), you'll need to collect all of the findBy*() response instances and pass that list as the second argument to mockDomain().  You are using mockDomain() incorrectly in your example -- you must tell mockDomain() which instances to mock in order to receive them back in a findBy*() call.

Comment: mockDomain(Client, instances) makes sure that the findByName method is wired in the unit test. So Client.findByName("Test") should return the saved client instance.

Comment: @Ruben If I move the first two lines of Cris' test to after the save, and modify the first of those two lines to include the saved instance, the findBy will work.  Cris is not passing instances to his mockDomain() -- that's what I am trying to get across.

Comment: @Jim But client.save(), which if successful adds the client instance into the mocked domain, is invoked before using the dynamic finder.

Comment: @Ruben I cannot make Cris' example work, even if the save is successful.  Do you also expect 'instances' to include 'client' by the end of the test?

Comment: @Jim I wouldn't expect the instances list to contain the client instance after saving. And a quick small test also shows that this is not the case.

Comment: @Ruben There were two components to my last reply.  You fully answered the trivial one.  After careful testing, I can assure you that Chris' code will not work even if the save is successful.  That is, res will still be null.  Meanwhile, my solution above works, except that I must also mock the domain at the outset.  I would like to have a deeper knowledge of this issue since your insight may simplify my tests, but I struggle to understand your perspective.  Does your "quick small test" look just like the test method in the question?  Does your solution -- fixing the save() -- really work?

Answer (score 1):

Saving the client can fail without an exception being thrown, which would explain why res is null. Try the following code below, so you can see if and why saving the client failed.

```
client.save()
if(client.hasErrors()){
// Saving failed, look in client.errors to see the specific reason
}
```